# Rule-based sorting of experts in teams

Tags: algorithm, sorting, design-patterns, graph-algorithm, rule

This is a real-world problem based on an activity I am organising, involving about 20 different people. So, the aim is to sort these people into teams of 4 or 5, according to a set of rules like:

1. Person (1) **cannot** be in the same team as person (4).
2. (3), (8) and (16) are all electronics experts, so they need to be in different teams for better skills balance.
3. Person (9) **must** be in the same team with person (14), to satisfy their a mentor-student relationship.
4. Persons (1)-(12) belong to **cohort 1**, the rest belong to **cohort 2**. The teams **must** be balanced in a way to include people from both cohorts, as close as possible to a 50-50 split.

Any recommendations of algorithms/methods/libraries that can help?

Comment: branch and bound algorithm, plus functions to determine the "worth" of a team based on programmatic rules. Try whipping up something, and come back with any problematic code (and a SSCCE if at all possible). But, frankly, with so simple a ruleset, you might be better off penciling in rule #4 and then refining it by applying the other rules through inter-team swapping. Unless you have to do this many, many times with different people...?

Comment: Well... the classic approaches are **Mixed-Integer-Programming**, **Sat-Solving** and **Constraint-Programming**. But in order to tackle this problem, more modelling-work is needed, especially the objective. L1-loss (mean deviation from 50-50)? L2-loss?

Comment: @Iserni The ruleset is just an example, it is actually a bit more complex than this, as each person needs to satisfy at least a few conditions (everyone has a role, a mentor not necessarily from a different cohort, a team preference etc.). I do not think it can be optimally done manually.

Comment: A MIP would be my first choice, but it might not find a feasible solution in a reasonable time. A genetic algorithm could work. Use the genes to determine an order for "inserting" the people into the teams. The insertion algorithm can be a fast-running heuristic that will attempt to satisfy the most constraints by placing a person on one team or the other.. The goodness of a trial solution can be a score based on the 50-50 split and the number of constraints violated. The premise of this algorithm is that by making decisions about people in a particular order will lead to better solutions.